# Getting "JSON Binding deserialization" error while json mapping to object

Tags: java, json, serialization

Getting below error while deserialization

javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'birthDate' because of: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 1999-04-11. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonProperties#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.

I have added below annotations still not working

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonbProperty
@JsonbDateFormat(value = "yyyy-MM-dd", locale = "Locale.ENGLISH")
public Date getbirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for my class, I was using localdatetime. I had to add this anotation over the entity column

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
public LocalDateTime effectiveTimestamp;
```

Comment: Also I see it is a Date class not a LocalDate

Comment: Should it be Localdate? Do you have any idea what could be the fix for type Date?